# Есть ли альтернатива for?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно вывести максимальное число из динамического массива, а как это сделать я понятия не имею. Цикл for не удобен.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
cout << "Ввведите количество гор" << endl;
uint16_t size = 0;
cin >> size;
int* pointer = new int[size];
cout << "Теперь введите высоты этих гор" << endl;
for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) 
    cin >> *(pointer + counter);


delete[] pointer;
```

Comment: а где ваш динамический массив?  Хотябы его покажите в инициализированном виде, чтобы понять чем же неудобен цикл for

Comment: `cout << *max_element(...)` ? А еще можете использовать цикл `while`. Или `do..while` :)

Comment: И чем же именно вам `for` не удобен?

Comment: for ведь постоянно крутит значение переменной, а я не могу остановить его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот с применением вектора

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> x;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) //ввод массива
  {
     int t;
    cin >> t;
    x.push_back(t);
  }
  int max = x[0];
  for(int y : x) //перебрать массив X
    if(y > max)
        max = y;
    cout << endl << max;
    return 0;
}
```

и да еще один без for :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> x;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
     int t;
    cin >> t;
    x.push_back(t);
  }
  int max = x[0];
  int i=0;
  while(i<x.size())
  {
    if(x[i] > max)
        max = x[i];
        i++;
  }
    cout << endl << max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если заранее знаете количество элементов вектора, то сразу создайте вектор с таким размером, чтобы потом не пришлось терять время на  push_back

Answer (score 6):

А вы сразу, не плодя лишних циклов...

```
int maxval = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) 
{
    cin >> *(pointer + counter);
    if (*(pointer + counter) > maxval) maxval = *(pointer + counter);
}

cout << maxval;
```

Можно чуууточку проще:

```
int maxval = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
for (int x, counter = 0; counter < size; counter++) 
{
    cin >> x;
    if ((pointer[counter] = x) > maxval) maxval = x;
}
cout << maxval;
```

Ну, или, как я говорил в комментарии -

```
cout << *max_element(pointer,pointer+size);
```

Comment: не могли бы мне объяснить что такое `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` и зачем тут он?

Comment: @SKIP Минимальное значение, которое может принимать переменная типа `int`. Для поиска максимального значения. Если бы я работал с готовым массивом, то можно инициализировать начальное значение максимума первым элементом, а раз я так не могу - использую это значение.

Answer (score 4):

Сразу при инициализации можете найти максимальный элемент (смотр. ответ от `Harry`). А если хотите потом, то у вас же есть размер  массива `size`. Вот и используйте:

```
//так как это высота гор, то все числа положительные    
int  max = 0;
while (size--) {
    if (max < pointer[size])
        max = pointer[size];
}
cout << max;
```

А если дело дошло до стандартных контейнеров(такой ответ принят), то есть более оптимизированный  контейнер для численных расчетов:

```
//вся ваша программа
int size;
cin >> size;
std::valarray<int> v(size);
for (int& i : v)
    cin >> i;
cout << v.max();
```

Comment: А если все введенные элементы - отрицательные?...

Comment: @Harry, речь о высоте гор

Comment: Тогда логичнее использовать `unsigned int`, нет?

Comment: Впринципе так нужно, может я не очень серьезно отнесся к данному вопросу....